# Delay next action in SKAction.sequence after runBlock occurs (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The `duration` property for `moveTo` isn't followed when inside a `runBlock`, allowing the subsequent action in a sequence to get executed immediately when it should only get executed after `duration` seconds.

Code A (sequence properly executed):

```
let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)

itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), moveAction, SKAction.runBlock {
    itemB.removeFromParent()
}]))
```

Code B (sequence not properly executed):

```
let badMoveAction = SKAction.runBlock {
    let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
    itemB.runAction(moveAction)
}

itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), badMoveAction, SKAction.runBlock {
    itemB.removeFromParent()
}]))
```

In `Code A`, `itemB` gets removed after the `moveAction` completes (about 2 seconds). This is the correct sequence.

In `Code B`, `itemB` gets removed before `badMoveAction` finishes, meaning `itemB` never moves from its original position. It's as if the duration property isn't honored in `Code B`.

How can we move `itemB` as in `Code B` but ensure the next action in the sequence doesn't start until `badMoveAction` completes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do what you want.  i just re-arranged the code a little bit.

```
itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([

    // wait for half a second
    SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5),
    SKAction.runBlock({

        // after waiting half a second, get itemA's position
        let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)

        // move to that position, after we get there, remove itemB from scene
        itemB.runAction(moveAction, completion: {
            itemB.removeFromParent()
        })

    })
]))
```

Answer (score 2):

**EXPLANATION:**
When you execute a block of code, it is executed asynchronously. This means the code will be executed on a separate queue while the rest of your code continues to execute.

In the case of **Code A** this does not cause an issue because the moveTo action is run on the current queue, completed and then the runBlock is fired.

In the case of **Code B** this creates an issue because the badMoveAction block is fired, it begins executing on a separate queue and the code continues on to the next piece which happens to be the remove action that removes itemB, while the badMoveAction was executing in the background. If you did something else in that runBlock you will see them run simultaneously, but because you removed it, everything is removed.

**Solution**
If you are saying you want to add badMoveAction to a node and have that calculate every time you could do something like this:

```
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, moveAction(), removeAction])

func moveAction() -> SKAction {
    let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration:2.0)
    return moveAction()
}
```

*Code is just for example of what you can do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the parentheses after "runBlock" didn't work. Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi Sorry, I updated my answer, that was a mistake. Unfortunately I am not at a computer to test any code so I removed code from my answer as well. I believe the issue is with the fact that runBlocks execute instantly and only once. You need to create an SKAction for each action you want and put them in a sequence. Is there a reason you want to use runBlock?

Comment: Because we need multiple activities to get executed as one logical block (e.g., calculate new position and move item A, remove item A and update label). Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you call a function which will calculate the new position, generate an SKAction to move Item A with a completion block that will remove itemA and update the label and then have that function return it. Then you can just have your node execute the returned action?

Comment: We can try it, but are you saying there is no way in Swift to chain functions together in a linear fashion?

Comment: Does my edit help at all? in terms of what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72883/discussion-between-chrissukhram-and-crashalot).

Comment: Thanks for the update. To answer your chat question, we want to run complex actions in sequence as opposed to simple actions like moveTo. More specifically, these "complex" actions require multiple activities (e.g., calculate new position then move item) that function as one logical block. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but you can just set up a function that will generate an entire sequence (your logical block) and call it every time you want to use it. For example, if your logical block is to calculate new position, move to the new position, wait 5 seconds, determine whether to return or stay, return (or stay). If this was an action that you wanted to call "planNextAction" then you can have a function that does all of that, puts the determined actions into a sequence and returns the entire sequence. A function would just be a reusable runBlock that executes on the same thread.

Comment: Our goal is to chain these logical blocks without hard coding wait durations in between. For instance if block A takes 5 seconds to move an item and block B removes the item, block B should wait until block A completes before removing the item. Both blocks act like functions in that they encapsulate multiple actions. Is this possible?

Comment: I have continued the discussion in chat as it is getting a bit long here but the answer is yes, by using functions as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can try an alternative solution:

```
itemB.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)) {
     let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
     let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
     itemB.runAction(moveAction) {
         itemB.removeFromParent()
     }
}
```

Trailing closure in `runAction` function is a completion block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the caller of your `runAction`. Use `self` to call it. Because you are using a `runBlock` and you say that the `parasite` runs the action inside it, there is no need to call the function on `parasite`. So call it like that:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), moveParasite]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using "self" in place of "parasite" didn't change anything. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the runBlock executes immediately, and the duration of the `moveTo` is not respected. The sequencing of both *Code A* and *Code B* is correct, but in the latter case it seems like it is out of sequence since the `moveTo()` duration is not respected.

As a solution to the issue of running a block of code resulting in one or more actions, whilst respecting the duration, try this code:

```
func notSoBadMoveAction() -> SKAction {
    let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
    return moveAction
}

itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([   
   SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), 
   notSoBadMoveAction(), 
   SKAction.runBlock {
       itemB.removeFromParent()
   }]))
```

This code does use the full duration for the move, and it can replace some (but maybe not all other) other uses of runBlock. If you want to, the function can take parameters as well, and as such be made into an even more general case of generating actions.

**ADDITION:** Here is an alternate version of the function displaying the possibilites to add actions, and calculate stuff within the function:

```
func myMoveAction(pos: CGPoint, duration : NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let realDest = CGPointMake(pos.x, pos.y)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: duration/4)
    let moveAction2 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(realDest.x/2, realDest.y/2), duration: duration * 2/4)
    let moveAction3 = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: duration/4)
    return SKAction.sequence([moveAction, moveAction2, moveAction3])
}
```

Comment: When you say the runBlock executes immediately, what do you mean? In Code Block A, the final runBlock doesn't execute after moveAction completes. Thanks for the help, just trying to understand Swift!

Comment: It seems like the runBlock just ignores all duration-stuff, and does everything in a split-second... I'm just referring the documentation, and what I see happening in my playground. ;-)

Comment: To be clear, the earlier comment should say that the final runBlock doesn't execute *until* after moveAction completes. Hence, the confusion. :)

Comment: My understanding is that the _immediate_ part of a runBlock, relates to that given runBlock and that the current block is executed immediately. The sequencing is kept, so in your original code,  the final runBlock is indeed executed after the badMoveAction. But the badMoveAction is executed without the duration. Using functions as in my answer avoids this 'immediately' issue

Answer (score 0):

`SKAction.runBlock` has a duration of `0.0`. Fortunately, the `duration` property is mutable.

`badMoveAction.duration = 2.0` should delay the block long enough to run after the action within the block is finished.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the duration property didn't change anything. Did this work for you?

Comment: Did you also check that the `speed` property is set to something higher than 0?