# Can't understand how to use run(_block:) new to programing SPRIKE KIT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode8

```
let logMessage = SKAction.run() 

{
    print("Reached bottom!")
}


let sequence = SKAction.sequence(
    [actionMidMove, logMessage, wait, actionMove])
```

To create a run-block action, simply call run(_ block:) and pass in a block of code to execute.

How do I call run(_ block:)  ?

Comment: Finde example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957369/delay-next-action-in-skaction-sequence-after-runblock-occurs-swift

Comment: Could  not find any help there :(

Comment: It shows multiple examples or run- and completion blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right **Swift 3** syntax is:

```
let logMessage = SKAction.run{ 
    print("Reached bottom!") 
}
```

You can find details to the [official](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417692-run) Apple docs

Even auto-completion could come to your aid:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: `SKAction.run() {print("Reached bottom!")}` is valid code, but I only like doing this method when it is a completion block, not a block that is getting passed in (Swift has no way of knowing if the last parameter is a completion block, or just a block being passed in)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you explain why you don't like it? Why is the concern about knowing if it's a last parameter or just a block a problem/concern?

Comment: it is about reading code,  you see `function(){block}` then you know that block is designed to run at the end of the function, you see `function({block})` then that means that the function should be using that block as a parameter, not to run it at the end of the function